# How to connect a micro controller to a CDC device?

Tags: serial

I have a device that exposes a [USB CDC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_communications_device_class) port recognized by a PC as a virtual com port.

I need to connect a micro controller to this device through its USB port.
How should I do? I'm looking for a kind of ftdi that would handle the host side of USB.

Comment: https://www.hobbytronics.co.uk/usb-host-serial

Comment: @Passerby That looks interesting but I wouldn't use it for anything other than a one-off device.  The firmware is tied to a specific bootloader that's only available on chips sold through hobbytronics (the firmware is presumably encrypted).  Also, the chips are only available direct from them (not e.g. via Mouser, Digikey, or Newark/Element 14).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find some niche products that may fill this by hoogline "USB Host CDC". As these are niche products your mileage may vary.

The other method is to use a USB OTG or Host compatible microcontroller and roll you own. Many of these microcontroller may have code available so you don't have to code a CDC compatible host driver. At the same time, you could throw a cheap SBC computer like an Raspberry pi or similar to do this instead. A RPi zero may cost the same as a microcontroller that supports usb host and programming time.

Comment: Thanks, I will use stm32F4.